# Arrays Sum User Input Recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, user-input

So I'm trying to write a recursive method to sum an arraylist of integers and create a client to test it.

My Class is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SumArray
{
    public static int ArraySum(int[]arrayList, int sum, int size)
    {
        sum = sum + arrayList[size];
        size--;
        while(size >= 0)
        {
          return ArraySum(arrayList, sum, size);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

My Client is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArraySumClient
{
   public static void main()
   {
      System.out.print("The sum of the array is: ");
      SumArray r = new SumArray();
      int[] myList = new int[5];
      myList[0] = 1;
      myList[1] = 2;
      myList[2] = 3;
      myList[3] = 4;
      int size = myList.length-1;
      System.out.println(r.ArraySum(myList, 0, size));

   }
}
```

These both compile and work. However, I'm trying to figure out a way for the user to input the size of the array and the numbers in the array instead of my inputting the array size and numbers inside the client.

Comment: Read input values from command prompt. Just google it.

Comment: `while` can be safely replaced with an `if`, because your "loop" never survives past the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use java scanner to take input from cmd prompt
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `ArrayList` instead of an array.  It would let you dynamically add as many items as needed:

```
public static void main() {
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myList.add(1);
    myList.add(2);
    myList.add(3);
    myList.add(4);

    // compute sum
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer value : myList) {
        sum += value;
    }

    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
}
```

Using this approach, you would not need to ask how many items the user intends to add.

Comment: Not only the size OP want to _inputting numbers inside the client_. Those should be dynamic.

Comment: Offcourse! I know that. better to give some suggestions instead of writing code here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @Satya suggested, you could read input from the command line as command line argument and extract them as:

```
Integer[] array = Stream.of(args).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(size -> new Integer[size]);
```

You do not want to pass the length of the array to the method `ArraySum` which, I suppose you are doing because you are not able to remove an element from the array. One way of doing this is by using `Arrays.copyOf()` using which you could copy a part of the array as another array.

I think it is always good to use `List` of theses situations.